# How to pass values in cookie from form-input?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm trying to get value from text field input

in my testservlet.java

```
        out.println("<form id='name' action='' method='post'>");
        out.println("<input type="text" name='hostname'>");
        out.println("<input type="submit" value="Submit">");
        out.println("</form>");
        String name = request.getParameter("hostname");
```

and put it in a cookie

```
        boolean flag = false;
        Cookie[] ck = request.getCookies();
        for(Cookie c : ck){
            if(c.getName() != null){
                out.println(c.getName());
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }


        if(!flag){
              Cookie c = new Cookie("name",name);
              c.setMaxAge(25);
              response.addCookie(c);
              out.println("user was add " +c.getName() + ", " + c.getValue());
        }
```

But it doesn't work, what's wrong?

Comment: To get form submission results you need to supply URI where they will be retrieved. You have **empty** `action` in your `form` tag.  Where do you believe your `POST` data should go?

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah, now it works, I did not notice it :(
thks